# MYSQL TripleDES algorithm generates proprietary junk (no cipher understands it)

Tags: mysql, encryption, base64, tripledes

I am trying to use MYSQL methods for encrypting a string using key with the value 'symmetric_encryption.php' (just for example). However output is a garbage that no other cipher could understand. I tried everything but it produces the same garbage no mater what. It can decrypt this garbage but what the point if no other tool can do the same?

```
select HEX(DES_ENCRYPT('test12345','symmetric_encryption.php'));
```

Output is FFDAF66D7309B91B9DC5CBC25F7514AFC4 when should be e52099eb5e0f81e8bd24315f3a80ac7c

(check for example here https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/)

```
select TO_BASE64(DES_ENCRYPT('test12345','symmetric_encryption.php'));
```

Output /9r2bXMJuRudxcvCX3UUr8Q= when should be 5SCZ614Pgei9JDFfOoCsfA==

There are plenty of online tools where outcome of TripleDES encryption could be validated.

MYSQL output stays out of line. The results produced by MYSQL could not be decrypted by any other cipher tool but ony mysql itself.

I set the block size

```
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ecb';
```

what should not be necessary as it is default and my encodings are all UTF8

is it a dead end or there is a solution ?

Comment: I'm kind of worried you're using DES in 2016. Is this to support some legacy system?

Comment: Yes. I know. But it is exactly the problem. Legacy system.

Comment: MySQL expands the ciphertext by one byte. I wonder why that is. Why do you switch to AES when you try to use DES? `SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ecb';`

Comment: Fair enough. Keep in mind DES was completely cracked over ten years ago and it's worthless from a security perspective now.

Comment: Regarding  SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ecb'; It was the only way to somehow hint MYSQL that ECB blocks are required. There is no way to hint about padding. I think PKCS5 is what only supported (without been documented). My problem is that there is a stored procedure that needs to encrypt some sensitive pieces of data and information is floating to an application that is old and could only understand TripleDES. There is nothing in between stored procedure and this app that can do massaging of the data.

Comment: DES might be cracked but here is TripleDES that is very secure. There is no any suggestions that TripleDES could be easily broken.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what MySQL does, when it encrypts something with `DES_ENCRYPT`:

- Triple DES with EDE and a 192 bit key (168 bit without parity bits)
- The 192 bit key is generated from the given passphrase using OpenSSL's `EVP_BytesToKey` with one iteration and MD5
- CBC mode, but the initialization vector, that was produced by `EVP_BytesToKey` along with the key, is zeroed out, so it's essentially a 0x0000000000000000 IV
- Somewhat PKCS#5 compatible padding is used (last byte denotes the number of padding bytes): the code doesn't actually initialize the other padding bytes, so this will essentially result in [ISO 10126 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#ISO_10126).
- The first byte of the ciphertext is not actually encrypted, but denotes the used key from the key file, but this is only of interest if no passphrase was passed to `DES_ENCRYPT`; it can be safely disregarded.

If you want to see for yourself, the code is located in root/sql/item_strfunc.cc. [Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/67f1aaf1e77f9d9357074551c19457c3) is the interesting part of that file. Needless to say, this is not a very good way to encrypt stuff.

Comment: *"is it a dead end or there is a solution?"* - The solution would be to implement it yourself if you really need it in a language of your choice. I've provided a sort-of "specification".

Comment: Got it. They use hard coded CBC blocking but this is not the problem. Problem is that they pad string by * when it seems have to be the number showing count of padded characters. This is the definition of PKCS#5 padding (6.2) as defined in the RFC:

The padding string PS shall consist of 8 - (||M|| mod 8) octets all having value 8 - (||M|| mod 8). So if they pad 3 symbols it should be 333 not ***

Comment: Right, they say this in a comment, but I really don't see how this works in the code. That's why I suggested that you regard this as ISO 10126 padding, which would unpad correctly if you were to decrypt this. It's definitely not PKCS#5 padding, but the last byte denotes the length of the padding in the same way that PKCS#5 does it. For example, if 3 padding bytes were added, then this code would probably produce `**3`

Comment: if (tmp_arg.append(append_str, tail) ..)
    goto error;
  tmp_arg[res_length-1]=tail;      So he first adds the tail number of * to the end of the input and than replaces the very last char by the value of tail indicating how many * he actually padded. (append_str is *******). He should be just putting tail value as a padding. Also he is always putting 127 at the first byte of the response just to show that encryption was done using pass phrase (rather than key). Other ciphers are not aware about it. At the end it is unfortunately a poor implementation of the algorithm.